# browser cache problem with umijs throws uncaught syntax error in production

Tags: browser-cache, umijs

This app is built using umijs and antdesign pro for frontend and node js express server for backend hosted on a Ubuntu server and Cloudflare is used for DNS management.

If the app is being loaded for the first time on any browser, it works as intended. But if we refresh it, it gets stuck on loading and outputs this specific problem:

for chrome:

[image: umi error chrome]

for firefox

[image: umi error firefox]

The app is then only re-usable after purging cache (Cloudflare) and then persists again when refreshing. The problem does not exist when using "serve" and serving the files locally.

Answer (score 1):

This issue produces by a service-worker. try without service-worker.